# Center image in relationship to width

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center a navigation bar on my webpage. I have the min width to be 945px and then 50% of the screen if it's past that width. I now want it centered so I shift it left 50% but then I need to adjust the margin. How do I code width/2?

```
#navBarImg {
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    width:50%;
    margin-left:-(width/2);
    top:50px;
    z-index:2;
    min-width:945px;
}

<body>

<div id="container">
<div id="navBar">
<img id="navBarImg" src="../Navigation/navBarBGImg.png" />
<img id="navBarLogo" src="../Navigation/navBarLogo.png" />
<div id='navMenuPart1' class="navMenu">
<ul>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Research</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Team</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>News</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Courses</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Outreach</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

set your margin-left and margin-right to auto and it will center the div (also take of the left: 50%). If that doesn't work, post your code on jsfiddle.net

Comment: If they leave position :absolute - auto margins will not help

Comment: True. That should be changed to relative.

Answer (score 0):

```
#navBarImg {
    position:relative;
    width:50%;
    margin: 1em auto;
    z-index:2;
    min-width:945px;
}
```

Address your buffer requirements via margin values not top. Relative positioning + auto margins will do it.

EDIT for structure:

```
  #navMenuPart1 {
        position:relative;
        margin: 1em auto; // adjust top / bottom to suit
        top:50px;
        z-index:2;
        min-width:945px;
        background : url("../Navigation/navBarBGImg.png") no-repeat;
    }
#navBarLogo {
     position:relative;
     display:block;
     float: left // your choice
     margin: auto // top right bottom left - use this to position it
     clear:both;
}

    <body>

    <div id="container">
    <div id="navBar">
    <div id='navMenuPart1' class="navMenu">
    <ul>
       <li><a href='#'><span>Research</span></a></li>
       <li><a href='#'><span>Team</span></a></li>
       <li><a href='#'><span>News</span></a></li>
       <li><a href='#'><span>Courses</span></a></li>
       <li><a href='#'><span>Outreach</span></a></li>
       <li><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <img id="navBarLogo" src="../Navigation/navBarLogo.png" />
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

So the intention here is to use the background image property for your navbar image. Position the interface UL over that as well as the logo. The logo "floats" in that space. Now depending on your UL css - this above might have some layout conflict with your UL but I think this illustrates a better approach

Comment: Z-index works with any "positioned" element. In terms of what you are trying to accomplish with it - I don't know unless you provide more markup. Absolutely positioned elements need to either have their margin-left or left values set manual via percentages or another definitive unit. Relatively positioned elements will respond to the "auto" margin in a way which achieve your desired effect. Absolutely positioned element's "auto" is simply irrelevant because they are not composed against another element in the same manor relative positioned elements are.

Comment: now that it is relative my logo which was over it now is not on top

Comment: perhaps you should revisit your goals and how you are going about accomplishing them. If you provide complete markup I could provide a more complete answer, but in absence of that structure, the best I can do is suggest you re-approach your markup strategy

Comment: i put the structure above

Comment: Updated - let me know if you have any questions. I'm assuming whatever you are doing with the UL element, you've got covered so I did not add any CSS to cover it's layout

Answer (score 0):

This does work,

```
width:50%;
min-width:945px;
margin:auto;
position:relative;
top:50px;
```

but using relative positioning essentially "uses" the visible position, as well as the original position. To get around this, you need to contain it somehow. I'm assuming this navigation bar is horizontal (since it's so wide). You also mentioned a logo, which needs to be visible.

Wrap the logo and nav bar in a "header" div or something (if you're already doing this, it requires another layer of wrapping for everything in the header *except* the nav bar), and set that div to `position:relative;width:100%`, and give it the height of your nav bar plus whatever else needs to go in it. Then give the nav bar

```
position:absolute; /* Absolutely positioned, relative to its container */
bottom:0;
right:50%
margin-right:-25%; /* OR -472.5px */
```

You cannot have both an "auto"-looking margin and scalable width. So using -25% (half of scalable width) works for displays greater than double the item's width, while -472.5px (half of the min-width) works for displays less than double.

**Update:** in response to [your new link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17712848/centering-a-web-page) in the comments: You give `#page` a width of 100% - but 100% *of what?* To give it a width relative to that of its parent, the parent width must be defined.

I suggest adding a rule such as `html, body{width:100%}` (I also tend to set margins to zero, because I don't like the automatic margin created at the top of every page). This will set those elements' width to that of the window, so the percent width you give these elements has a reference point.

Comment: I am still slightly confused. I have a container div > nav div > navbarimg and logoimg

Comment: What I mean is that if you want the navBar to always be centered, but with varying width, yet also a definite minimum width for windows less than X pixels wide, you have to use JS.

Comment: Otherwise, you have to compromise. You can make it definitely centered for windows less than double the navBar width, but slightly off-center for windows greater than double. OR the opposite: slightly off-center until the window has double the width of the navBar, then it will be centered correctly.

Comment: can u point me to a javascript example? if so that would be great.

Comment: how would I "You can make it definitely centered for windows less than double the navBar width, but slightly off-center for windows greater than double. "

Comment: Sorry, I've just been waiting until I have a chance to set up an example with JS on a live server (I don't want to give you a fiddle because it would be harder to make the Result section wider than 1890px).

Comment: To do that, use the CSS I put in my code block above, but use `margin-right:-472.5px;`

Comment: this was as far/ as close to getting it work as possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17712848/centering-a-web-page

Answer (score 0):

With a relatively positioned element, the browser can auto-center the horizontal axis. You do this simply with `margin:auto;`. Keep in mind, this will auto-center the element *in relation to its container element*. So, the thing that screws up a lot of people here is that the container element does not have a defined width, and therefore the `margin:auto;` doesn't know how to render because it is relative to the parent element.

### EDIT

Also, an `<img>` is an inline-block element. You will need to make it a block-level element for `margin:auto;` to work correctly. You can do so like this `display:block;`.

[A working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/3Zr2k/)

```
#navBarImg {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    min-width:50px;
    width:50%;
    margin:auto;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: this was as far/ as close to getting it work as possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17712848/centering-a-web-page