# Centering a web page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center my webpage. Also there is a min 1000px with and it scales up. Currently my page as it scales it is off centered 30%-center-70%. I am confused as to why this is happening. If anyone can explain why this is happening that would be great.

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Title</title>
<style type="text/css">


#page {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    width:75%;
    margin:auto;
    min-width:1000px;
    z-index:0;
}
#pageImg {
    position:absolute;
    width:75%;
    margin:auto;
    min-width:1000px;
    z-index:1;
}
#navBarImg {
    position:absolute;
    width:75%;
    margin:auto;
    min-width:1000px;
    z-index:2;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page">
    <img id="pageImg" src="../Navigation/backgroundImg.png" />
    <div id="navBar">
        <img id="navBarImg" src="../Navigation/navBarBGImg.png" />
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try 50% on your page width... I think you got your result from doing a 75% of 75%...

example - http://jsfiddle.net/rob_towner/q8vKK/

```
#page {
position:relative;
display:block;
width:50%;
margin:auto;
min-width:1000px;
z-index:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is additional code to consider that you haven't posted yet. This can be inferred because the code you did post works as you intend it to. [A working example](http://jsfiddle.net/TkGGS/) (the 1000px width won't fit in the default window size of the rendered window, use the sliders to expand it and see your code is working).

Your CSS I used:

```
#page {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    width:75%;
    margin:auto;
    min-width:1000px;
    z-index:0;
}
#pageImg {
    position:absolute;
    width:75%;
    margin:auto;
    min-width:1000px;
    z-index:1;
}
#navBarImg {
    position:absolute;
    width:75%;
    margin:auto;
    min-width:1000px;
    z-index:2;
}
```